# Azure Management API via SPA (and diff. API Management)?

Tags: azure

I want to call this url:

[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{workflowName}/runs/{runName}/actions/{actionName}/requestHistories?api-version=2016-06-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/%7BworkflowName%7D/runs/%7BrunName%7D/actions/%7BactionName%7D/requestHistories?api-version=2016-06-01)

In order to do so:

1. Do I need to set up an API through API Management in the portal? Or can I call it directly?
2. Can it be called directly from a Single Page (Web) App? Or will it have CORS issues?
3. Do I need to register the web domain/app in order to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are trying to call is part of `Azure REST Management API`. There are certain things that you would need to do before you can call these APIs. The steps are very well documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/.

To answer your specific questions:

> Do I need to set up an API through API Management in the portal? Or
> can I call it directly?

You can call these APIs directly. No need to set up API management to do so.

> Can it be called directly from a Single Page (Web) App? Or will it
> have CORS issues?

You should be able to call these APIs directly from a SPA. You should not encounter CORS issues.

> Do I need to register the web domain/app in order to do so?

No, as such there is not need to do so unless you are planning on calling these APIs from a web application. You can very well call these APIs from a console application if you like.